# What happens if I receive a payment after deleting the payment request

Tags: wallet, address, multibit

I just started with Bitcoin using Multibit HD. I clicked request payment and sent the address to someone. I then deleted the request. What happens if bitcoin is sent to this address? Will it just appear in the payments window?

Answer (score 2):

You still own the address, so the payment would be received fine, you would just lose the additional notes you may have added to the payment request.